# In clause parameters with SPEL

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-jpa, spring-el

I'm trying to pass multiple In Clause parameters using Spring-El, my query is:

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "select a.* from ACC a where (a.iban, a.currency) in (:#{#ibanAccounts.accountNumber} , :#{#ibanAccounts.currency})")
    List<ACC> getAccount(@Param("ibanAccounts") List<AccountDetails> ibanAccounts);
```

But I'm getting following error:

```
EL1008E:(pos 14): Property or field 'accountNumber' cannot be found on object of type 'java.util.ArrayList$SubList' - maybe not public? 
org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:(pos 14): Property or field 'accountNumber' cannot be found on object of type 'java.util.ArrayList$SubList' - maybe not public?
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.readProperty(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:224)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:94)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.access$000(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:46)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference$AccessorLValue.getValue(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:374)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:88)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getTypedValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:131)
```

> In AccountDetails the field is present with public getter.

Can anyone please guide me what's wrong?

Comment: ibanAccounts is a list, when you say `{#ibanAccounts.accountNumber}`  which acocuntNumber(of which ibanAccount) should the framework read?

Comment: @pvpkiran I want to pass all the accountNumber of all the ibanAccounts present in the list. May be my syntax is wrong.

Comment: I believe what you are looking for is collection projection docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.12.RELEASE/…. So you need to use something like this `ibanAccounts.![accountNumber]`

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for is [collection projection](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.12.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-collection-projection).

So you need to use something like this

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "select a.* from ACC a where (a.iban, a.currency) in :#{#ibanAccounts.![accountNumber]} , :#{#ibanAccounts.currency})")
List<ACC> getAccount(@Param("ibanAccounts") List<AccountDetails> ibanAccounts);
```